# How to fix PolymorphicExpression error on upper bound type

Tags: scala

I have issues with implicit conversions that fails to recognize types. I forged minimal (not)working example to make things clear. But I still failed to grasp why my code is rejected and how should I rewrite it.

```
trait AnyK[X]

trait Simple[X, U[_]]
trait Knot[X, U[_ <: X]]

def simple[X, U[_]] = new Simple[X, U] {}
def knot[X, U[_ <: X]] = new Knot[X, U] {}

val pass : Simple[Any, AnyK] = simple
val fail : Knot[Any, AnyK] = knot
val passNow : Knot[Any, AnyK] = knot[Any, AnyK]
```

`pass` and `passNow` pass compiler. And `fail` as you could guess from its name fails with the following error:

```
PolymorphicExpression.scala:11: error: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [X, U[_ <: X]]test.package.Knot[X,U]
 required: test.package.Knot[Any,test.package.AnyK]
  val fail : Knot[Any, AnyK] = knot
                               ^
one error found
```

---

#### Update

Since it has unclear, I made slightly more complicated example to show why implicits make things harder.

```
trait AnyK[X]

trait Simple[X, U[_]]
trait Knot[X, U[_ <: X]]

implicit def simple[X, U[_]] = new Simple[X, U] {}
implicit def knot[X, U[_ <: X]] = new Knot[X, U] {}

val pass = implicitly[Simple[Any, AnyK]]
val fail = implicitly[Knot[Any, AnyK]]
```

I get the following error message:

```
PolymorphicExpression.scala:25: error: could not find implicit value for parameter e: test.package.Knot[Any,test.package.AnyK]
  val fail = implicitly[Knot[Any, AnyK]]
                       ^
one error found
```

The error message presented is much less descriptive that one I had above without doubt. So that is why I avoided using implicits in the original example.

Answer (score 0):

> I have issues with implicit conversions that fails to recognize types.

It's hard to say since your minimal example doesn't include any implicit conversions.

When you don't annotate `knot` with type parameters compiler obviously can't infer them correctly (sometimes compiler has troubles with inference of higher-kinded types)

```
val fail : Knot[Any, AnyK] = knot
```

but when you annotate them explicitly everything works

```
val passNow : Knot[Any, AnyK] = knot[Any, AnyK]
```

So just annotate them when necessary.

Comment: I mentioned implicits to show that I could not annotate types, because they should be implicitly inferred. Like `implicitly[Knot[Any, AnyK]]` should automatically choose implicit method `knot`

Comment: @ayvango Thank you for clarification. Unfortunately I'm pessimistic regarding that the implicit conversions will work. Could you provide more context why it's important in your situation that the type constructor U can't accept a type that is not a subtype of X?

Comment: I'm implementing type level list for higher-kinded types. `TListK` should accept types like `Seq`, `Set`, `Option`. But in the most general form, it should also work with types that accepts subtype of given type. I have plenty of such types, like trait `Interpreter` that could interpret any subtype of `Script`

Comment: For time being I switched to `trait Limit {type Param; type Kind[P <: Param]}` and use it as parameter for the `knot` method. Scala type system is really awkward.

Comment: @ayvango Regarding higher-kinded types there are some unpleasant bugs in compiler https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10186 https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9337

Comment: @DmytoMitin Lately I have asked bunch of type level questions. Not it's time for metaquestion. How can I decide if some behaviour is bug or feature? When should I bother scala developers with issue ticket and when not?